# is this at least mildly secure php code?

Tags: php, mysql, security, post, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a BUNCH of $_POST variables being sent in via a long form and instead of hard coding each one with a `mysql_escape_string()` is it ok for me to do the following? I don't know if this is actually safe and/or viable code.

```
foreach ($_POST as &$post_item){
    $post_item = mysql_escape_string($post_item);
}
```

I'm fairly certain that because i'm using the &, it's passing it in by reference, not value, so i'm actually changing the value in the $_POST.

Also, should I use `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead?

EDIT: I am using PDO and prepare() along with the above method. Does this take care of it for me?

Comment: In PHP5 nothing is passed by value. Everything is passed by reference.

Comment: I think in fact only objects and resources are by default passed by reference

Comment: If you are using PDO and prepared statements you should _not_ use mysql_real_escape_string at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not use `array_map()`?

```
array_map(mysql_real_escape_string, $_POST);
```

But in reality you should be using parametrized/prepared statements.

`mysql_real_escape_string()` takes the current database character set into account, `mysql_escape_string()` does not. So the former is the better alternative in comparison.

Edit (following up the OP's edit to the question):

Since you already do PDO prepared statements, there is no need to modify your values. PDO takes care of everything, that's the whole point of it (**If you really put all data in parameters, that is** - just concatenating strings to build SQL statements leads to disaster with PDO or without). Escaping the values beforehand would lead to escaped values in the database.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should be using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, if you're going to go that route. But the correct way to make sure the variables are safe to send to the database is using [Parameterized Queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Using_Parameterized_Statements) which are provided in PHP through either the [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) functions or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous comments, another benefit to using parameterised queries is that the database will be able to do better optimisations and probably use a cached query plan so you will get better performance.